# Column doesn`t exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Try to learn hibernate + jpa, don`t know what to do with this. Error when getting by id.

JDBC exception executing SQL [select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.login,u1_0.password,r1_0.id,r1_0.name from user u1_0 left join role r1_0 on r1_0.id=u1_0.role_id where u1_0.id=?]

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column u1_0.role_id doesn`t exist

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private UserRole role;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQ92.png)

Tried to debug but no results

Comment: Sounds like the column doesn't exist. Did you change the class schema for this after already creating the DB?

Comment: no, in pgadmin the same error btw, in tables are correct columns

Comment: User is a reserved word in most databases, so I'd suggest NOT using it as your table name to avoid issues (maybe this one). What do you mean "in PGAdmin the same error", or that the tables are correct? How have you created the tables exactly?

Comment: If your table is not in the default schema you need to specify it by setting `@Table(name = "user", schema = "your_schema")`